# Download MODIS product for the whole globe with R

Tags: r, modis, download

I need information about global vegetation index (EVI) and GPP, derived from MODIS satellite data. To download the data, I've tried using both the MODIS package and the MODIStsp package in R, but it usually lets me only download a certain region/tile/bounding box. I have tried

```
MODIStsp(gui             = FALSE,
          out_folder      = 'data/modis_data/',
          out_folder_mod  = 'data/modis_data/',
          selprod         = 'Vegetation_Indexes_Monthly_1Km (M*D13A3)',
          bandsel         = 'EVI',
          sensor          = 'Terra',
          start_date      = '2001.01.01',
          end_date        = '2012.12.31',
          verbose         = TRUE,
          spatmeth        = 'tiles',
          start_x = 0,
          end_x = 35,
          start_y = 0,
          end_y = 17,
          out_format      = 'GTiff',
          #compress        = 'LZW',
          #out_projsel     = 'User Defined',
          #output_proj     = '+proj=laea +lon_0=-73.125 +lat_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs',
          delete_hdf      = TRUE,
          parallel        = TRUE
 )
```

which would just download all tiles, but that would take very long.  Is there a (faster) way to get a certain MODIS product for the whole Earth surface?